# Wordpress: javascript not working in wp-admin on server

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have made a custom post type of name "vendors" in wp-admin. Now what i want is that user could not enter duplicate post title. 
So what am doing is when user enter post title i check it by query in save custom post function in functions.php thatis the entered post title not exist it should save post but if it already exist I apply Delete query and delete that post and display javascript alert "this entry already exists" and  by javascript window.location redirect user to wp-admin/post_new.php to reneter. 
It was working very fine on **localhost**. But when I uploaded on server. Delete query is working fine but it is auto redirecting on wp-admin/edit.php. Neither window.location nor alert is working. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Upload a fresh wp-admin folder to the server. That is the correct solution. It worked for me.

The reason for this issue is sometimes there may be some problems occured during the previous upload of wordpress folder.